# Light blocking walls

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera, lighting

I have an issue with light blocking walls (with Cycles). I am using following material settings which works like a charm, but... I have some parts where the walls block themselves and creates weird patches. I cannot explain why.

Picture worth a thousand words.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved...
I have removed material and unchecked "Camera" under "Object properties"/"Visibility"/"Ray Visibility".

[image]